# Yeoman grunt test Pattern "path_public/todo/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match to any file

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm new at yeoman staff so I'm following the good tutorial just at the bottom of the main page [here](http://yeoman.io/) and all works are nice other than the **grunt test**.

I get a Pattern `path_public/todo/test/mock/**/*.js does not match any file` and the test failed.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/whisher/6621191) is a gist with all the stack. Does anybody here have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a path like path_public/todo/test/mock/ in your application

Comment: No, give a look at https://gist.github.com/whisher/6621191

Comment: @Whisher exactly what BKM said do you have that `path_public/todo/test/mock` in your application? If not then in your `karma.conf.js` comment out that line which will sit within `file: [files_here]`

Comment: I've got this files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ], BUT in my deploy set up with yeoman there is no mock folder :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://newtriks.com/2013/06/11/automating-angularjs-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/)

> WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/newtriks/src/newtriks-dev/js/angularjs-grunt-example/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.

there is the fix thanks the same.

Answer (score 3):

From http://newtriks.com/2013/06/11/automating-angularjs-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

> Run grunt karma grunt karma All tests pass! Chrome 27.0 (Mac):
>   Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.085 secs / 0.018 secs) But wait….there is a
>   warning: WARN [watcher]: Pattern
>   "/Users/newtriks/src/newtriks-dev/js/angularjs-grunt-example/test/mock/**/*.js"
>   does not match any file. Let’s fix this. I tend to prefer to add
>   directories as required and for now I have no mocks so lets comment
>   out the include. Open karma.conf.js and comment out the line with
>   'test/mock/***/.js'. Run grunt karma again and the warning should be
>   gone. Note: If you want to follow the same logic for karma-e2e.conf.js
>   also this will ensure the warning is also fixed for the end-to-end
>   tests.

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you'd like to know how to actually add a mock objects, check http://dailyjs.com/2013/05/16/angularjs-5/

Comment: This link goes to a dead page, but it's the first time I've seen someone suggest an answer to what the **/mock/*.js stuff is actually for. Any suggestions for a newer explanation?

Comment: I think I was pointing to this link http://dailyjs.com/2013/05/15/angularjs-5/ although it's been a loooong time :)

Comment: And in the actual text he mentions the code is here: https://github.com/alexyoung/djsreader/commit/7b4bda96b787b7707582567db927f12cc80c5d27